# JSON file not reading

Tags: python, json

```
import json
import io

username = input('Enter your username ') #Input
password = input('Now enter your password ') #Input

usernamelow = username.lower()
```

username input converts to lowercase

```
auth = {
    "users": usernamelow,
    "pass": password
    }
```

the JSON string that is writ to the JSON file

```
dump = json.dumps(auth) #Gathers data
print (dump) #Debug print
with open('auth.json', 'a') as outfile:
    for line in outfile:
        json.dump(auth, outfile, indent=4)
```

(Dumps AUTH)
adds data to  the JSON file ^

```
with open('auth.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Basically this is a school project I'm working on and when I append to the file more than once it gives me an extra data error. This is the JSON that appears when the script is ran:

```
{
    "pass": "testpass", 
    "users": "testuser"
}{
    "users": "testinguser", 
    "pass": "testingpass"
}
```

I appear to get this error:

> ValueError: Extra data: line 4 column 2 - line 7 column 2 (char 52 -
>   110)

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You need to put commas between each user's details and enclose the whole thing in `[...]`

Comment: How so? Sorry for such a stupid question btw

Comment: as @AhsanMalik says in his answer, the easiest way is to put all those dicts into a list and then use `json.dump` on the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be the missing comma between the entries

Another way is, first to collect all existing data from your file in a list (of dictionaries) and then append the new input. this might be usefull for checks of duplicates

```
import json
import os

auth_list = []
file_name = 'auth.json'

if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        auth_list = json.load(f)

print(auth_list)

username = input('Enter your username ')
password = input('Now enter your password ')

usernamelow = username.lower()

auth = {
   "users": usernamelow,
   "pass": password
}
auth_list.append(auth)

with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(auth_list, outfile)
```

This might be also a usefull ressource https://realpython.com/python-json/

Comment: Ok this worked for storing it now but I'm moving on and trying to recognise it.
Like
usernamelow = username.lower()
if usernamelow == auth_list[users]:
    print ("EXISTS")

Comment: Something like that

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the following error tells us something:-

```
ValueError: Extra data
```

The data you're trying to load is not properly formatted in JSON. The correct JSON formatting would be:-

```
[{
    "pass": "testpass", 
    "users": "testuser"
}, {
    "users": "testinguser", 
    "pass": "testingpass"
}]
```

A better practice would be to input all the data once in a list of dicts, and then you can dump it into the file as a whole:-

```
with open('auth.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(auth_list, outfile, indent=4)
```